# Uneven parabola using chart in vb?

Tags: vb.net

I'm very new to visual basic. My program has you enter the parameters (a,b,c,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax & # of data points) to plot a parabola. The parabola looks fine when more datapoints are inputted. The problem is if there is say 4 datapoints, the parabola is uneven by 2 points. I'm really stuck on finding a solution so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
Public Sub FillGraph()
    myChart.Series(0).Points.Clear()
    myChart.Series(0).ChartType = _
        DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line

    If IsNumeric(txtxMax.Text) And IsNumeric(txtxMin.Text) And IsNumeric(txtyMax.Text) And IsNumeric(txtyMin.Text) Then
        ymin = CDbl(txtyMin.Text)
        ymax = CDbl(txtyMax.Text)
        xmax = CDbl(txtxMax.Text)
        xmin = CDbl(txtxMin.Text)
        dataPts = CDbl(txtDataPts.Text)


        a = CInt(txtA.Text)
        b = CInt(txtB.Text)
        c = CInt(txtC.Text)
        Dim x As Integer
        For x = CInt((-dataPts / 2)) To CInt(dataPts / 2)
            myChart.ChartAreas(0).Axes(0).Maximum = xmax
            myChart.ChartAreas(0).Axes(0).Minimum = xmin
            myChart.ChartAreas(0).Axes(1).Maximum = ymax
            myChart.ChartAreas(0).Axes(1).Minimum = ymin
            myChart.Series(0).Points.AddXY(x, (a * (x ^ 2)) + (b * x) + c)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabCtrl.SelectedIndexChanged
    If TabCtrl.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        Call FillGraph()
        Call FillLbls()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    myChart.Series(0).Color = Color.Red
    myChart.Series(0).BorderWidth = 5

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make sure the user has entered enough points to draw a smooth parabola? Imagine drawing a circle with only four points: it would be a square, so four points is not enough.

Comment: My problem is that there are 3 points on the right side and only 1 on the left. I want there to be 2 on either side. I know this is possible for a parabola with y=ax^2, but not y=ax^2+bx+c. Is it possible to have the data points plot two on either side?

Comment: It will not always be possible. For example, if the user wants a graph of y=x^2 but xmin=1 and xmax=2 then there will not be a minimum in the chart area for you to have two points on either side. (Also, you can set `myChart.ChartAreas(0).Axes(0).Maximum` etc. *before* the loop.)